# cmake out of source build not working for nested source directories

Tags: cmake

I am having a directory structure of my source code as follows:

```
.
├── build
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── libs
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── ext
│   │   └── include
│   │       └── json.hpp
│   └── int
│       ├── CMakeLists.txt
│       └── net
│           ├── CMakeFiles
│           │   ├── CMakeDirectoryInformation.cmake
│           │   └── progress.marks
│           ├── cmake_install.cmake
│           ├── CMakeLists.txt
│           ├── include
│           │   ├── connection.hpp
│           │   └── conn_manager.hpp
│           ├── Makefile
│           └── src
│               ├── CMakeFiles
│               │   ├── CMakeDirectoryInformation.cmake
│               │   ├── libs.dir
│               │   │   ├── build.make
│               │   │   ├── cmake_clean.cmake
│               │   │   ├── cmake_clean_target.cmake
│               │   │   ├── DependInfo.cmake
│               │   │   ├── depend.make
│               │   │   ├── flags.make
│               │   │   ├── link.txt
│               │   │   └── progress.make
│               │   └── progress.marks
│               ├── cmake_install.cmake
│               ├── CMakeLists.txt
│               ├── connection.cpp
│               ├── conn_manager.cpp
│               └── Makefile
└── main
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── config
    │   └── config.json
    └── srcs
        ├── CMakeLists.txt
        ├── main.cpp
        ├── samvaadak.cpp
        └── samvaadak.hpp
```

"build" is a folder from which I am running cmake.  It runs and creates the final output executable inside build/dist/bin.  But it also creates lot of intermediate inside the source tree (libs and main) and making it cluttered.

The top level CMakeLists.txt file looks like this.

```
project (samvaadak)
subdirs(main libs)
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/dist/lib)
set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/dist/lib)
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/dist/bin)
```

Intermediate CMakeLists.txt files have the following content:

```
subdirs(src)
```

And, the CMakeLists.txt file for inner folder(s) where the source files are present, is like this:

```
include_directories(${samvaadak_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/int/net/include)
include_directories(${samvaadak_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/ext/include)
add_library(nettu conn_manager.cpp connection.cpp)

set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/dist/lib)
set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/dist/lib)
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/dist/bin)
```

How to tell cmake that build outside of **libs** and **main** folders and just build everything inside build?

Comment: With out-of-source build CMake **never** generates any file in source dir unless script explicitely asks for that. Remove files generated by CMake in source dirs and try again.  `Intermediate CMakeLists.txt files have the following content: 'subdirs(src)'` - Your `lib` directory doesn't have `src` subdirectory. Note, that [subdirs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/subdirs.html) command is deperecated, use [add_subdirectory](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/add_subdirectory.html) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable in source builds:

```
set(CMAKE_DISABLE_IN_SOURCE_BUILD ON)
```

Also recommended:

```
set(CMAKE_DISABLE_SOURCE_CHANGES ON)
```

They need to be used before the first `project()` command.